# Goのテンプレートのif文で表示を分けたい

Tags: go, templates

Goのテンプレートでテンプレート変数の値によって表示するViewを分けたいのですがテンプレート内での`if`の使用方法がよくわかりません。調べて見ましたが公式リファレンス以外の例を見つけられず、それを参考にしましたができませんでした。例えば以下のばあい

```
{{ if .Num ne 1}}
 <p>Num is not 1</p>
{{else}}
 <p>Num is 1</p>
{{end}}
```

と書いてみましたが、実行するとこの部分以降が表示されなくなってしまいました。GoのTempleteでのif文の使い方についておしえてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

テンプレート内で利用できる`eq`、`ne`などの演算子は実際には関数として実装されているので、オペランドを演算子の後に配置する必要があります。（ポーランド記法）

例えば、`.Num != 1`のような式は`ne(.Num, 1)`のような関数呼び出しとして扱う必要があるので、正しい書き方は以下のようになります。

```
{{ if ne .Num 1 }}
 <p>Num is not 1</p>
{{else}}
 <p>Num is 1</p>
{{end}}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。できました! ということは例えば`func hoge(buzz int)int{}`のような自作した関数も今まで`{{ .Fuga | hoge }}`というようにしていましたが、`{{ hoge .Fuga }}`のようによびだせますか。

Comment: 自作の関数でも同じ方法で利用できます。ちなみに`{{ .Fuga | hoge .Num }}`のように書くと引数の一番最後に`.Fuga`が追加されて`{{ hoge .Num .Fuga }}`と書いたのと等しくなります。

Comment: なるほど、勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。